# React Router NavLink does not render activeClassName when mapped

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The activeClassName of React Routers NavLink does not work when mapped as shown in the following code. The view receives the links from its container as props where they are mapped. Everything works well, including the standard className, but the activeClassName doesn´t work. It works when I add a NavLink manually outside the mapping but I cant find the mistake. Any help appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from './style.scss';

class NavView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <ul>
            {this.props.links.map(function(link, index) {
              return <li key={index}> <NavLink to={link.slug} className="navLink" activeClassName="current" >{link.slug}</NavLink></li>
            })}
          </ul>
      );
  }
}
export default NavView
```

Comment: What does the data in `this.props.links` look like? Seems possible that the pattern matching of the `to` prop vs what the current URL is might be off.

Comment: It is an array of JSON Strings.  links: Array(4) 0: {title: "Home", id: "home", uid: "home", slug: "home", parent: null, …}

Comment: Try adding a preceding `/` to the slug so it becomes e.g. `/home`. Also ensure that if you have any nested routes that they are properly accounted for in the path matching. `https://example.com/#/home` will match `/home` but `https://example.com/#/foo/home` will not.

Comment: Thanks jered. The `/`is already in, thats what devtools show.  `<a class="navLink" href="/home">home</a>` I also don´t have nested routes so far and the routing itself seems to work.

Comment: Double check that the actual value of the actual React prop includes the slash, not just the `href` attribute of the anchor tag DOM element. You can use the Chrome React Developer Tools to inspect the React component hierarchy. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite certain that you simply need to add a `/` slash to the beginning of your routes' link slugs.

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from './style.scss';

class NavView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <ul>
            {this.props.links.map(function(link, index) {
              return <li key={index}> <NavLink to={`/${link.slug}`} className="navLink" activeClassName="current" >{link.slug}</NavLink></li>
            })}
          </ul>
      );
  }
}
export default NavView;
```

React-router is quite specific and picky about matching URL patterns. If your route is `/home`, `<NavLink/>` will only match when the `to` prop is also `/home`, *not* `home`.

Comment: this deserves 100 thumbs up! Simple mistake, but hard to catch. Wasted about an hour on this. Thank you!